# Python best practices for Importing module inside my package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'm a bit confused (actually a lot) with Python packaging path system.

I have this project:

```
myproject/
    package1/
       setup.py
       src/
          __init__.py
          module1.py
          module2.py
          module3.py
       tests/
          __init__.py
          test_package1.py

    package2/
       setup.py
       src/
          __init__.py
          module1.py
          module2.py
          module3.py
       tests/
          test_package2.py

    package3/
       setup.py
       src/
          __init__.py
          module1.py
          module2.py
          module3.py
       tests/
          test_package3.py
```

These packages should be published in private repository after CI process (if tests passed).

**Important:** Package1 uses package2 while package2 uses package3.

So `setup.py` of package1 looks like this:

```
setuptools.setup(
    name='package1',
    version='1.4.0.dev1',
    install_requires=['setuptools~=50.3.2',
                      'boto3~=1.17.0',
                      'pandas~=1.3.4',
                      'package2~=1.4.0.dev1'],
    package_dir={"package1": "src"},
    packages=["package1"],
    include_package_data=True,
    setup_requires=['pytest-runner'],
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    python_requires=">=3.6"
)
```

`setup.py` of package2 looks like this:

```
setuptools.setup(
    name='package2',
    version='1.4.0.dev1',
    install_requires=['PyYAML~=5.3.1'
                      'package3~=1.4.0.dev1'],
    package_dir={"package2": "src"},
    packages=["package2"],
    include_package_data=True,
    setup_requires=['pytest-runner'],
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    python_requires=">=3.6"
)
```

The CI flow:

1. I'm running `pip install .` for each package (from corresponding package directory)
2. From package3 directory running tests: `python -m pytest tests -vvv`
3. From package2 directory running tests: `python -m pytest tests -vvv`
4. From package1 directory running tests: `python -m pytest tests -vvv`

Tests for package2 and package3 passed successfully, but the last step - when running pytest for package1 it complains on `ModuleNotFoundError` in package2:

module1.py (of package2):

```
from module2 import AwsService
...
```

`AwsService` is just a class defined in `module2.py`.

I changed the import to: `from . import AwsService`, reinstalled the package and re-ran the package1 tests again. This time pytest complained about import in package3:

module1.py (of package3):

```
import module2
...
```

So I changed the import to `from . import module2` and tests started to run.

But in module3 of package2 I have `from module2 import AwsService` and it's ok, so how can I know when I must do relative import and when not?!.

I'm completely confused of all this path behavior.

Maybe my `setup.py` is not good or project structure or the way I'm testing it?

Comment: `_init_.py` should be `__init__.py`. And the convention has it that `src/` is usually named after the package, thus `package1/` etc instead of `src/`.

Comment: Note that requirements.txt shouldn't be relied upon for installation. That should be in `setup.py` (`setup_requires`), and then just `pip install .` for each package (in their respective package directories). Testing is slightly different though.

Comment: Your problem is likely that, because the packages are not properly installed, the `PYTHONPATH` settings are wrong (or non-existent), and the packages can't find each other. Internally, the package can find its own modules, but not from other packages. You do mention package3 relies on (imports) package2, but is that tested and verified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my problem was just to assign the path to myproject to PYTHONPATH:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/yuri/projects/myproject/
```

When you install package locally via `pip install .` and perform `pip freeze` you will see that your package was installed, but you will also see the path near your package and the path is like that: `file:///Users/yuri/projects/myproject/package1` as kinda reference to the original location and Python doesn't see it. So you have to add the path manually.